# Fixing Invalid signature when decrypting fernet token

Tags: python, cryptography

i am relatively new to pyhton and the cryptography module, so i'm trying to learn the basics of encrypting and decrypting.
It all works fine when i encrypt a file and decrypt it on the same program, but if i try to just run a decrypt code on a pre-encrypted file (i used the same key, of course) i get an InvalidSignature error, followed by an InvalidToken.

Now, i assumed that for some reason the key didn't match, but they are indeed the same.
Then i thought that for some reason i was passing a string instead of a byte to the functions, or that there are some sort of conversion errors that might alter the encrypted message. But the encrypt-decrypt code works, so i can't figure why the decrypt-only should face errors.
At last, i had a look at the source code for the decrypt function, and tried to figure out if the time stamp had something to do with the error i get, but i couldn't get anything relevant since i'm not too experienced.
This is the encrypt-decrypt code: given a password by the user it encrypts and prints a file, that can decrypt right away.

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

print("Insert password: ")
password_str = input()
password = password_str.encode()
salt = os.urandom(16)

kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), length=32, salt=salt, 
iterations=100000, backend=default_backend())

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
f = Fernet(key)

message = "A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.".encode()
token = f.encrypt(message)

file = open("text_encrypted.txt", "wb")
file.write(token)
file.close()

file = open("text_encrypted.txt", "rb")
data = file.read()
file.close()

token = f.decrypt(data)

file = open("text_decrypted.txt", "wb")
file.write(token)
file.close()
```

Now, that works just fine and i get the two files that contain the encrypted and decrypted message.
If i delete the:

```
message = "A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.".encode()
token = f.encrypt(message)

file = open("text_encrypted.txt", "wb")
file.write(token)
file.close()
```

part, i should be left with just a decryption code, that should work on a previously generated encrypted file, that should be decrypted by the same password.

I'm obviously missing something maybe trivial, since it raises both invalid signature and invalid token.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption key you’re using is a result of a PBKDF2. In order for PBKDF2 to return the same encryption key it must get the exact same parameters. That includes salt, which in your example is generated randomly every time.

You need to store the generated salt together with the encrypted file in order to be able to decrypt it later.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didn't pay attention to the random generator. It was silly of me because it's something i know, but for some reason i started to think about more exotic problems.
Anyway i was on the right track when looking for a non-matching key, but i excluded that option (wrongly)
For anyone else: basically urandom does not have a "seed" so it generates different salts every time. On the other hand, a random function with a seed produces always the same set of pseudo-random number when called, so it should produce the same salt.
Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @MarcoR just to be clear: using the urandom is the correct way, salt needs to be generated by CSPRNG. Seeded PRNG are almost certainly not cryptographically secure. You should store and reuse the salt you generate, it can be a plaintext in a database or appended to the encrypted file.

Comment: For the application i had in mind the salting isn't that relevant, so i could even avoid it, but thanks for your comment, i agree that seeded randoms give way less entropy to the code.
I will work on storing the salt like you suggested, so that i'll learn more about the cryptography module